# Machine Learning with fixed and variable inputs and multiple outputs

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, regression, random-forest, linear-regression

I've been doing machine learning and neural networks for a couple months, and finished a 5 months online course of it last year, but I'm struggling in an specific scenario:

Let's say we've got this data: **X1**, **X2**, **F3**, **F4** and **Y1**

```
X1 and X2 are possible to change.
F3 and F4 change only with time and arbitrary.
Y1 only changes as a result of X1, X2, F3 and F4 changing.
```

I've collected thousands of samples ready to train, but I don't know what type of algorithm should I use.

**This is how I want to use it:**

I want to "reach" a desired target value of **Y1**, setting the combination of values of **X1** and **X2**, respecting the existing and unchangeable values of **F3** and **F4**.

E.g.

```
[X1, X2] = run_algorithm(Y1, F3, F4);
```

And what if I also decide to include these **X1** and **X2** in the algorithm too, so it finds the most efficient way of doing it knowing the already existing values of **X1** and **X2**.

E.g.

```
[X1, X2] = run_algorithm(Y1, F3, F4, X1, X2);
```

Comment: Are all these variables time series? IF so, you seem to have a problem of [optimal control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control). Have you tried applying [a sequential model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning)?

Comment: @Emre Well, kind of. E.g. Let's say I want to keep my room at a "fixed" lightning. At this situation my variables X1 and X2 are my lightbulbs, Y1 is a light sensor, F2 is the time of the day and F3 the percentage of clouds in the sky.

Comment: In that case you might not even need machine learning. I'd try using a [PID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) first. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txftR4TqKYA) [are](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BDjZYGHupE) two videos for inspiration. (I'm assuming you really want a physical system, not a software simulation.)

Comment: @Emre The thing is, I don't want it to try and fail and fix, I want it to learn how it behaves, because not all rooms are the same, not all rooms have the same ammount of windows, or the same ammount of lightbulbs, or what if I can achieve the desired lightning in this specific room by just pulling up the curtain, instead of turning on the lightbulbs, but this won't work in another room. So I'm betting the idea of learning the behavior of anyroom. In this scenario.

Comment: If you're running a control loop (PID) it would detect the light level in reach room individually and adjust accordingly. No need to learn parameters. This design also makes it easy to smoothly transition when the environment changes.

Comment: Sounds like regression is what you're need. More specifically GLM.